# is it possible that I don't have the /etc/bluetooth folder?

Tags: bluetooth

[picutre of me looking for /etc/bluetooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brIDT.png)

went into cd/etc and did: ls -a

```
.                       e2scrub.conf     kerneloops.conf      os-release      shells
..                      emacs            ldap                 PackageKit      skel
acpi                    environment      ld.so.cache          pam.conf        snmp
adduser.conf            environment.d    ld.so.conf           pam.d           speech-dispatcher
alsa                    ethertypes       ld.so.conf.d         papersize       ssh
alternatives            firefox          legal                passwd          ssl
anacrontab              fonts            libao.conf           passwd-         subgid
apache2                 fprintd.conf     libaudit.conf        pcmcia          subgid-
apg.conf                fstab            libblockdev          perl            subuid
apm                     fuse.conf        libnl-3              pki             subuid-
apparmor                fwupd            libpaper.d           pm              sudo.conf
apparmor.d              gai.conf         libreoffice          pnm2ppa.conf    sudoers
apport                  gdb              lighttpd             polkit-1        sudoers.d
appstream.conf          gdm3             locale.alias         ppp             sudo_logsrvd.conf
apt                     geoclue          locale.gen           prime-discrete  sysctl.conf
avahi                   ghostscript      localtime            printcap        sysctl.d
bash.bashrc             glvnd            logcheck             profile         systemd
bash_completion         gnome            login.defs           profile.d       terminfo
bash_completion.d       groff            logrotate.conf       protocols       thermald
bindresvport.blacklist  group            logrotate.d          pulse           thunderbird
binfmt.d                group-           lsb-release          .pwd.lock       timezone
brlapi.key              grub.d           machine-id           pydfrc          tmpfiles.d
brltty                  gshadow          magic                python3         ubuntu-advantage
brltty.conf             gshadow-         magic.mime           python3.10      ucf.conf
ca-certificates         gss              mailcap              rc0.d           udev
ca-certificates.conf    gtk-2.0          mailcap.order        rc1.d           udisks2
chatscripts             gtk-3.0          manpath.config       rc2.d           ufw
console-setup           hdparm.conf      mime.types           rc3.d           update-manager
cracklib                host.conf        mke2fs.conf          rc4.d           update-motd.d
cron.d                  hostid           ModemManager         rc5.d           update-notifier
cron.daily              hostname         modprobe.d           rc6.d           UPower
cron.hourly             hosts            modules              rcS.d           usb_modeswitch.conf
cron.monthly            hosts.allow      modules-load.d       resolv.conf     usb_modeswitch.d
crontab                 hosts.deny       mtab                 rmt             vdpau_wrapper.cfg
cron.weekly             hp               nanorc               rpc             vim
cups                    ifplugd          netconfig            rsyslog.conf    vtrgb
cupshelpers             init             netplan              rsyslog.d       vulkan
dbus-1                  init.d           network              rygel.conf      wgetrc
dconf                   initramfs-tools  networkd-dispatcher  sane.d          whoopsie
debconf.conf            inputrc          NetworkManager       security        wpa_supplicant
debian_version          insserv.conf.d   networks             selinux         X11
default                 ipp-usb          newt                 sensors3.conf   xattr.conf
deluser.conf            iproute2         nftables.conf        sensors.d       xdg
depmod.d                issue            nsswitch.conf        services        xml
dhcp                    issue.net        OpenCL               sgml            zsh_command_not_found
dictionaries-common     kernel           openvpn              shadow
dpkg                    kernel-img.conf  opt                  shadow-
```

I did not remove any folder.
Before noticing this today I thought the issue was just with my pc not recognising it. I should maybe mention that I am running a dual boot and bluetooth is working on windows (fast startup is turned off).
If the folder is truely missing is there any way to download it again?

Comment: What is your system?

Comment: Yes, looks like the folder is missing. Have you been able to use bluetooth before? Or are you sure your computer has the required hardware for it?

Comment: Is it Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: yes, on windows I'm perfectly able to run bluetooth. I have a double boot with fast startup turned off.

Comment: My system is Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Try installing the bluez package (again?) to recreate the /etc/bluetooth directory.  sudo atp-get update     sudo apt-get install bluez

Comment: @ubfan1 thanks. It worked I do have the bluetooth folder back now but I still cannot conncect anything. It says: " No Bluetooth found, plug in a donle to use bluetooth"

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously possible if you removed the `/etc/bluetooth` directory.

All Ubuntu releases have this directory with some `conf` files in it.

Comment: I don't recall doing that. But to be fair do you know how I can get it back if I really did delete my bluetooth folder?

Comment: You can create the `/etc/bluetooth` directory, boot from a LiveUSB and copy default files from there. And also set the same permissions to the directory and files.

Comment: How does that work, I have only had Ubuntu 22.04 for like a week and never used any other Linux before?

Comment: I can't get the question. You boot from an Ubuntu 22.04 LiveUSB and copy files from there to the installed system. Another way would be to re-install Ubuntu. But it is an overkill for 1 directory with 3 small files.

Comment: I don't know how to "boot from an Ubuntu 22.04 LIveUSB" but I guess I will figure it out. Maybe I should create a new forum post for that if I cannot manage to do that.

Comment: You boot the same way as you installed Ubuntu.

Comment: First you need USB installation media. Then you need to boot it. If you don't know how to boot a USB, you'll need to consult with your motherboard documentation. This is outside of the scope of the Ubuntu operating system (since it obviously hasn't been booted until you boot it...) Once you boot the USB, choose "Try Ubuntu". This is the live session